# Benefits of Private Constructor - Singleton Design Pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks, java-memory-leaks

I understand that it helps creates single copy of class.

I would like to know:

1. What is the harm in creating multiple such instances of a class ? since garbage collection will take care of it.
2. Is it that it helps when multiple classes/threads use it and Java may run out of memory ?
3. It helps avoiding memory leak ?
4. How to decide if singleton pattern is better for me use case ?

Or could you please lead me to resources that can be helpful to learn more about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See these,

[Design Pattern: Singleton Pattern, pros & cons](https://medium.com/@kiennguyen88/design-pattern-singleton-pattern-d5f600dcca0b)

[Singleton Pattern – Positive and Negative Aspects](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/307233/Singleton-Pattern-Positive-and-Negative-Aspects-2)

[Singleton](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton)